# Is there a way to see what kernel fuctions a specific driver has registered / exported?

Tags: linux, drivers

So it is my understanding that a linux device driver defines its access functions (open, read, release, etc) that are kernel fuctions that can be called to interact with the device.  I would also assume that more complicated drivers (audio, video) export a large number of such functions.  So my question is: given a specific dev is there a way to list the access functions that have been defined and exported for that driver?
Thanks